Do we want to give out career-advice?
We have a tag career-advice with one popular question. Career advice is generally considered a can of worms and is off-topic across the entire Network. The main reason being that this attracts a huge number of low quality localized questions (as they are valid for a specific person/situation).
So, should we make career-advice off-topic as well?

I would agree that career advice is probably a bit too noisy and specific to be of much use to anyone but the person asking the question.

The arguments you give (also from past experience on the network) seem valid enough to me to say 'yes off-topic'. There is now one good post with good answers, no need for more topics repeating the same I'd say.
